# Why are std::deque subarray sizes fixed?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, time-complexity, deque

**Background**

`std::deque` uses subarrays to store its elements. It has an additional book keeping data structure to keep track of its subarrays. This way, compared to `std::vector`, `std::deque` can grow faster from the back (O(1) compared to amortized O(1)), and much faster in the front (O(1) compared to O(n)). This is due to the fact that `std::deque` can just add a subarray at either end and only have to modify its book keeping data structure.

---

**Question**

What I don't understand is why the subarrays have their sizes fixed as explained [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque):

> typical implementations use a sequence of individually allocated **fixed-size arrays**

There are quite a few advantages of not having fix sized subarrays. For example, since the subarrays are fixed in size, any insertion in the middle will have to be O(n) complexity where n is the number of the elements to the closest end. However, if the subarrays are free to grow, insertion in the middle will be O(k) where k is the number of elements in the subarray which is much faster especially if the `std::deque` has a lot of subarrays. It's the same for deletion from the middle.

Is it because `std::deque` wants to keep its subarrays balanced? This can easily be mitigated by enabling subarrays to split or merge if they get too large/small. The complexity will just be O(k) where k is the size of the largest subarray. (Or the combined sizes of the smallest subarray and it's smaller neighbor)

Is it because fixed sized subarrays makes random iterating faster? For example if you want the nth element, you have to go through the book keeping data structure and add the sizes of all the previous subarrays making the complexity O(k) where k is the size of the book keeping 
data structure. But this is not a huge deal either since `std::deque` is advertised to be a doubly linked list with better caching anyways.

---

**EDIT:** `std::deque` is just a middle man between linked list implementation and array implementation. I guess my question has lost its original meaning and is just suggesting that it should behave more like a linked list than a vector

Comment: How hard do you have to think if I ask you what is `2*23`, now compare that how hard you have to think if I ask you what is `13 + 10 + 19 + 4`.

Comment: Also I don't agree with you that with fixed size buckets, insertion is order O(n). That's not what the documentation says nor is it necessarily true. Fixed size buckets make it easier to insert in the "middle" (you really need to define what you mean by that), than if you had randomly sized buckets

Comment: Middle means not the either end. And no, insertion in the middle would be O(n) as you have to shift all values from the insertion point to the end of the deque for all subarrays

Comment: It can't be O(n), it would be more like O(k) where k is the size of each bucket. I think you are confusing deque with linked lists.

Comment: If you have a deque of size 133, and you want to reach the bucket that contains index 97; if you know that each bucket has size 20, then to reach the bucket containing 97, you simply divide (integer division) 97 by 20, giving you 4, then at that bucket, you can do (97 - 4 * 20) to get 17 which is the index you are looking for. All in all O(1). Now to insert at that bucket, if the bucket is simply an array, then you just replace the element there with the new one. In total O(1). If the buckets are linked lists, it might be a bit more and also expanding the deque will incur some extra cost

Comment: @smac89 It would be O(n). Let me give an example: Given a deque with 5 subarrays each are the size of 5, and the deque is filled from 0-24 ascending. If you want to insert another 13 into the deque, you would have to put the new 13 into 14's position. The 14 would have to be pushed to the next subarray into 15's position, each of the elements in that subarray would be shifted and 19 would shifted into the last subarray. Then a new array will be created containing 24.

Comment: Comparing `O(1)` to `O(1)` isn't all that easy, as it tells the number of operations, not the total cost. A deque would be more of an `O(2)` (if that existed) compared to a vector. A `std::list` is also `O(1)` for `push_back` even though it requires a dynamic allocation each time.

Comment: I guess we are getting into implementation now, but left to me, I would not start shifting all the subarrays just to make space for one. If the subarray is full I would rather create a new subarray at that position, insert the new element into it, and fill it with elements from either subarrays on both sides of it if needed. This will be more of order O(k) I think

Comment: @BoPersson I'm not disputing `push_back()` as anything other than O(1).

Comment: Hmm, I think you're right about the O(n) though, because we still have to make sure all the elements are at the correct index...

Comment: @smac89 If you add a new array in with just one element, then not all arrays will be of the same size, and random iteration will no longer be O(1) like others pointed out.

Comment: But all the `push_back`s that are `O(1)` don't have the same runtime cost. Benchmarks show that deque `O(1)` is not faster than vector amortized `O(1)`. And making deque even more complicated will not help. :-)

Comment: @BoPersson interesting, I didn't know that. Maybe subarrays in deque are dynamic in size (all at once).

Comment: Actually, since buckets do not grow in size, just capacity, the new bucket will be the same size as the others. So if the deque wants to know it's size, it can have all buckets report how much capacity they have left

Comment: Sorry I was not clear. What I meant was that perhaps if the number of buckets gets too large, all of them gets put in newer, larger buckets.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What I don't understand is why the subarrays have their sizes fixed

Because that allows constant complexity random access which is required by the standard, as pointed out in the comments.

---

> But this is not a huge deal

I disagree, and presumably so would the standard committee.

> since `std::deque` is advertised to be a doubly linked list ...

It's not advertised as such.

Comment: I have already addressed that. Most use cases of `std::deque` I've seen are dealing with insertion and deletion. I don't think a drop in random access is crucial.

Comment: @PhotometricStereo, I think the problem is that you are seeing deque from the perspective of a linked list, whereas, it is more of a contender to vector

Comment: It isn't a "drop" in performance, it's a change in asymptotic complexity. The requirement is _O(1)_ random access, so changing to _O(k)_ cannot be compliant.

Comment: If _O(k~n)_ access is sufficient - you can just use a list in the first place.

Comment: I look at deque as a vector that will perform better for insertions

Comment: I guess my question is just an (extremely disputed) design suggestion.

Comment: Amortised constant time indexed lookup is guaranteed for std:deque. See the table of requirements in [sequence.reqmts], currently referenced in 26.2.3/14: "Table 88 lists operations that are provided for some types of sequence containers but not others. An
implementation shall provide these operations for all container types shown in the “container” column, and
shall implement them so as to take **amortized constant time**."

Comment: @rici thank you. I suspected as much, but I had a hard time locating the rule and started doubting my suspicion. Fixed the answer.